# Windows cmd dosn't find exe even if it's in the path

Tags: windows-7, command-line, path

I just installed strawberry perl.
It's bin directory shows in the path but windows refuses to run it unless I give the full path (I even tried to reboot to make sure all environment variables was correct).

PS.
Same problem if I start cmd as admin.

What can I do do fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a rogue " in the middle of your path. It looks like it could be messing things up.

```
...;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin";C:\ ...
```

I've also had a problem where a CRLF character has found its way into the path, so watch out for that. (Although in your case this isn't the problem, it could be for someone else reading this).

Comment: That will do it! Good catch RJ.

Comment: Good catch, that fixed it. (stupid java)

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the Perl.exe as an environment variable for Windows. Go into your my computer properties and there should be some sort of advanced tab or area that will allow you to create the environment variable. The variable will be "perl" and it will resolve to "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe".

Comment: No, that's not correct. If that where the case I'd have one environment variable for each exe I have, `C:\strawberry\perl\bin` alone contains close to 100 executable files.

Comment: While I agree, the vendor docs allude to the same method if you're having problems. Also there is the "use" directive that you can look into. http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Strawberry_Perl Though most of this is aimed at having multiple installs of Perl on your box. When in doubt, its Windows, try a reboot.